# Why does the light on the bottom of an optical mouse light up brighter when clicking or scrolling?

Tags: mouse

This seems like a very obvious question, but I could not find the answer anywhere. Why does the little light on the bottom of an optical mouse light up brighter (very briefly) when you click a mouse button, scroll the mouse wheel, or move the mouse?

I've tried [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_mouse), but that isn't giving me any helpful information. All it says is that the light is used so that a tiny camera can see the surface below it and detect motion. If that is so, then wouldn't the light becoming brighter actually be detrimental to this process, since it would momentarily change the picture? What is the point of the light becoming brighter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The brighter light is the real light that is used to track movement with enough reflectivity (and therefore enough accuracy) to translate fine movements precisely. The dimmer light serves only to give a vague picture of the surface to the optical sensors within the mouse, sufficient only to give a yes/no type answer: basically the mouse in this state can only tell "I moved!" without having precise information about the nature of the movement.

The sampling rate of the mouse's optical scanner is 1500 times per second, so what seems to you like a brief brightening is actually long enough to obtain hundreds of brightly lit, accurate samples. The dimly lit samples from before the light increased are not used; they are discarded. Thus, there is no risk of the light's increased brightness "changing the picture".

The reasons for brightening and dimming (rather than staying bright all the time) are three-fold:

1. Power management, especially important for a battery-operated
   wireless mouse
2. LED lifetime: LEDs last practically forever, but the
   low-power state serves to extend this even further.
3. Safety: the brighter light is more likely to cause eye damage if you look
   directly into it.

Comment: This is great answer, but it doesn't seem to explain why using the mouse wheel or mouse buttons should also trigger readings.

Comment: its very hard to click a mouse without moving it at all. Which is why many FPS gamers have the fire button on the keyboard.

Comment: I agree with Paul - I can click and scroll my mouse just fine without moving the cursor. And if the point of the brightening is to detect movement better, why would the light brighten when scrolling? Not often does one want to scroll and move the mouse at the same time.

Comment: The only time my mouse's light ever gets brighter when I'm doing any thing other than moving it around is if scrolling and I accidentally bumped the mouse - same with clicking:)